# Continue For Next loop in separate cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of number and I want to create a macro that will loop through each one, and return any value higher than 0.

The table would look something like this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And I would want it to return the column headers. So in that example I would want it to return the values 5 and 14 for the 2nd row.

So far I have:

```
For j = 0 To 11
    For i = 0 To 91

        If Cells(2 + j, 2 + i) > 0 Then
        Cells(16 + j, 2) = Cells(1, 2 + i)
        End If

    Next i
Next j
```

The issue with this is that it will only return one value in cells(16 + j, 2), which is the last value that this corresponds to. What I need is, once the condition has been met, for it to continue from that point, but enter the value into cells(16 + j, 3).

I considered perhaps an "Exit For" once it had met the condition, but couldn't work out how to continue on the next cell from where it had left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with what you said this should work:

```
Dim cont        As Integer

cont = 2

For j = 0 To 11
For i = 0 To 91

    If Cells(2 + j, 2 + i) > 0 Then
    Cells(16 + j, cont) = Cells(1, 2 + i)
    cont = cont + 1
    End If

Next i
Next j
```

Comment: That sort of works, but when it goes onto the next row (the +j) it doesn't go back to row 2. See screenshot: http://oi57.tinypic.com/ael7wh.jpg

Comment: ^it doesn't go back to column 2*

Comment: EDIT: I've solved that issue. I just move the "cont = 2" to after "For j = 0 to 11". Thanks Ygor!